# Possible to replicate a scheduling tool built in Microsoft Access in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sqlserver, access

My company has recently started using Salesforce Marketing Cloud. We are a team who send marketing emails, and are soon retiring our old email software.

At the moment, the email schedule is kept separately in a Microsoft Access Database, comprising several tables, with a frontend built from scratch with VBA by myself. There are several approval stages in the process, with account managers submitting a request for an email to be sent on a certain day, and the delivery team approving it. They then use the schedule to track their progress with the build, for example, waiting for approved data and artwork.

It became clear shortly after implementation that Marketing Cloud's Calendar could not replicate the functions we have built in our database, such as having a set amount of email slots per day, certain users being able to add more, embargos placed on certain days depending on the audience, etc.

So my question is, is there a way to link our Access Database with Marketing Cloud? I'm thinking for example, once the campaign is on the 'booked' table, to have some sort of trigger button which creates an email in Marketing Cloud, attach it to the correct campaign, use the job number for easy identification etc? Or any alternatives I may not have thought of?

I have limited experience with Marketing Cloud and almost no experience in cross-application/API stuff, so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Your best bet with your limited experience/knowledge of API would be to hire a 3rd party partner to build this for you.  I warn you it will likely be expensive.  You can talk to your SFMC rep to get some referrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article on how to create data extensions. This may help, but it is not that easy of a task to do what you are looking to do unless you are fairly technically savvy.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_new_data_extension/

Keith
kkonetzni@nimblejack.com

Comment: Thanks Keith - I'll check this out, might be what I need.